# Power connectors: 2.1mm and 2.5mm, 1.35 and 1.7mm

Tags: power-supply, connector, power-electronics, hobbyist

I refer to DC power connectors used for a wide variety of common consumer devices.

[image]

I notice that I have to specify between 2.1mm and 2.5mm when I want to purchase these online. Are the two interchangeable or is the tolerance so precise that 0.4mm makes a difference?

Separately, I have an existing 5V adapter with the smaller connector. I can't tell whether it is 1.35mm or 1.7mm. I am trying to purchase an adapter to convert it to 2.1mm/2.5mm. Same question: does it matter whether it's 1.35mm or 1.7mm, or is there a good way to find out what my connector is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DC barrel connectors are so tight that the outer diameter and inner diameter must both match between plug and jack. Otherwise they won't fit at all (2.1mm plug, 2.5mm jack) or they swim loosely (2.5mm plug in 2.1mm jack). The only spec that is slightly interchangeable is depth. But again, you can get really short ones that won't fit in a jack designed for longer ones.

As to a size adapter, don't bother. You won't likely find one for arbitrary sizes. Instead, cut off the old connector and replace it with screw or spring or push in type connector. Cheap, easy, convienent.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it matters.

“Barrel” connectors work by having exactly one spring (the outer contact of the jack) which pushes the plug sideways so that the center makes good contact as well as the spring.

In the 5.5 mm O.D. connectors, if you use the 2.5 mm I.D. plug in the 2.1 mm jack it will not make good contact because the outer housing of the jack may not allow the plug to be displaced far enough for the center to make contact, and in any case the spring will not be exerting the proper amount of pressure since the plug has less thickness. It may work but it will not be reliable.

In the reverse case, the plug will not fit over the center pin of the jack at all.

I am not familiar with the smaller connectors but I expect that you would find similar results.

If you are choosing a power jack for use in your design, and you are not looking for a specifically unusual one, I would recommend choosing the 5.5 mm O.D., 2.1 mm I.D. size. In my experience it is the most common in hobbyist electronics and related areas. Due to their use in the CCTV camera field, you can readily obtain both male and female adapters to screw terminals, which are handy for making temporary connections either to a power supply or device where the other end does not have a barrel plug/jack at all.

Comment: Separate question: why does the industry find it necessary to have both 2.1mm and 2.5mm?

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae I don't know. It's not a good idea to ask further questions in comments — fewer people will see them.

Comment: I've usually seen 2.5mm used on higher current connection. I guess it is a power requirements but not sure. Also, use center positive!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wonderful post by Digi-Key about using a toothpick, a pen, or multimeter test lead to quickly determine if it's 2.1mm or 2.5mm.

It's pretty hard to measure the inner diameter (ID) using a pair of calipers given the relative size difference.

https://forum.digikey.com/t/measuring-power-supply-barrel-plug-id-2-1mm-vs-2-5mm/401

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it matters

The dimension you refer to does matter -- 400 microns of center pin diameter is the difference between "fits" and "doesn't fit at all".

A pair of decent calipers is the correct tool for the job when it comes to measuring such small dimensions, by the way.

Comment: I have a set of digital calipers. For the smaller connector I am talking about, the outer diameter is 3.94mm. Any suggestions on how to measure the inner diameter?

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae Your calipers should have a second set of jaws opposite the "main" set -- those are used for measuring inside diameters :)

Comment: Yes, but too large to go into the 1.xmm hole. I looked at product samples on sale, and they come in either 4.0*1.7 or 3.5*1.35, so I reckon mine is 4.0mm*1.7mm.

Comment: I use my set of 0.5 mm sequence drill bits. Push them into the plug and find the best fit. Check the diameter of the bit with the calipers.